# Do not have permission to write to emptyDir

Tags: kubernetes

I have mounted a emptyDir volume with memory medium to a pod. Then I logged into the pod and tried to create a file in that volume path but I got a permission denied error.

```
touch a.txt
touch: cannot touch `a.txt': Permission denied
```

User I used is root. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: There is a known issue with emptyDirectory mounts, see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/2630 in that it is owned by `root:root` and permissions set to `750`, but since you state you're root I'm unsure if this is the cause.

Comment: Would you post the pod spec that you're using?  Also, what operating system are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Add :z or :Z as a workaround to your mount path to work properly with selinux:

```
volumeMounts:
- name: etcd-storage
  mountPath: /var/etcd/data:z
```

Comment: What does adding the :z do?

Comment: :z - multiple containers can share the persistent volume
:Z - a single container can mount the persistent volume

There's also 2 selinux booleans you can switch on for NFS storage, where you won't need the :z any longer for those.

Answer (score 2):

Disabling SELinux fixed the issue

```
setenforce 0
```